# Writing a https request function that triggers on a document creation

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to trigger an app engine task that triggers when a new document is created on my cloud firestore database, however I am unsure of how to tackle the problem. Right now I have an onCreate function that triggers but I'm not sure what to do on the app engine side of it.
Would I be able to send a http request from cloud functions and read it on the app engine side and then do a put http request to vary data in my database?

Comment: If you want to trigger some code to run when a document is created, you should probably be using Cloud Functions instead of App Engine.

Comment: I tried in the past, but I am struggling with the timeout of 9 minutes, so ideally I am trying to make the tasks (which last round 2 hours) happen on app engine and then get retransferred to firestore. I am really stuck however as I don't know what the procedure to accomplish something like this would be.

Comment: You'll want to use Cloud Functions to trigger, then offload the actual work to something else.

Comment: You could use pubsub to send a message to app engine to tell it what work you want to do.

Comment: Would I use a cloud function to trigger an .onCreate to start with or can I trigger a document creation from pub/sub directly??

Comment: If you had 5 minutes to chat privately it would help greatly as I am currently really stuck and not sure what to do. Kinda new to backend :(